# Sql insert fails

Tags: symfony, ssl, sql-insert

Hello I am trying to save an entity in Symfony, but I am receiving an error:

`INSERT INTO postfach (protocol, url, port, benutzername, passwort, ssl, tls) VALUES (1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1);`

SQL Fehler (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ssl, tls) VALUES (1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1)' at line 1

I think the problem might be the word ssl, because when I remove it it works fine. Is this some kind of reserved word?

Comment: Are ssl and tls columns of the postfach table?

Comment: [apparently ssl is a reserved keyword](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/)

Comment: Yes ssl is a column

Comment: I think this Silvester my question thank you